# rewrite rule wordpress custom url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I had an old website programmed for me and now i have migrated it to wordpress, but many websites still have links to the old urls and i want to redirect them to Wordpress because there are having a 404 response.

the old structure was: http://www.website.com/news/2013/june/01/slug-slug-slug-slug
the new in wordpress:  http://www.website.com/news/2013/06/01/slug-slug-slug

Note that i only need to change:

```
january -> 01
february -> 02
march -> 03
april -> 04
may -> 05
june -> 06
july -> 07
august ->08
september -> 09
october -> 10
november -> 11
december -> 12
```

Do i have to include something in wordpress' .htaccess or in the rewrite.php file? I heve been thinking that i only need to change the %monthday% variable from numeric to string... but if i update wordpress i probably need to change it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use mod_rewrite, you can do this with 12 rules. I am not familiar with wordpress itself and I don't know if there is an 'easy' way via the config of Wordpress itself. Add the following rules above the rule that sends all requests to Wordpress' index.php file:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)/january/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /news/$1/01/$2/$3 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)/february/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /news/$1/02/$2/$3 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)/march/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /news/$1/03/$2/$3 [R,L]
#etc...
```

As always, see [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for information about the syntax being used.

Comment: It does not work, but is is not throwing any error. Well, in wordpress it shows me 404 not found, so the redirection is not working properly. I have to explain that i have my wordpress in a /wordpress folder, so i have in the .htacces: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]

</IfModule> Is this afecting my rewrite rule? I know in urls i have to add mysite.com/wordpress

Comment: Yes, as I stated before, you have to add my rules before the rule that sends the request to the wordpress index file. In this case, put the rules behind `RewriteBase`.

Answer (score 0):

There will be 12 rules like this so you can have something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(news/[^/]+)/january/([^/]+/.+)$ $1/01/$2 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^(news/[^/]+)/february/([^/]+/.+)$ $1/02/$2 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^(news/[^/]+)/march/([^/]+/.+)$ $1/03/$2 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^(news/[^/]+)/april/([^/]+/.+)$ $1/04/$2 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^(news/[^/]+)/may/([^/]+/.+)$ $1/05/$2 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^(news/[^/]+)/june/([^/]+/.+)$ $1/06/$2 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^(news/[^/]+)/july/([^/]+/.+)$ $1/07/$2 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^(news/[^/]+)/august/([^/]+/.+)$ $1/08/$2 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^(news/[^/]+)/september/([^/]+/.+)$ $1/09/$2 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^(news/[^/]+)/october/([^/]+/.+)$ $1/10/$2 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^(news/[^/]+)/november/([^/]+/.+)$ $1/11/$2 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^(news/[^/]+)/december/([^/]+/.+)$ $1/12/$2 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Also make sure to have these rules on top, before any other rewrite rules.

Comment: Fixed it. Sorry there was an extra `(`

Comment: OK, now it is not throwing 500 error, but wordpress throws 404, so it is not working. I have wordpress in a folder: mysqite.com/wordpress for development and the url i am pasting are with the wordpress too, if i put 01 for january it works but with 'january' it does not work... Do i have to aad the wordpress to the rewrite rules you've paste to me?

Comment: If you place above rule just below `RewriteBase /wordpress/` then it should work.

Comment: Also I believe above code is in `/wordpress/.htaccess` is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct .htaccess is in that folder. Do i need to paste your code before or after wordpress default one?

Comment: This is worpress' default code:  # BEGIN WordPress <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /wordpress/ RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L] </IfModule>

Comment: No these rules should be placed **before usual wordpress rules**